# GWT / Bean/ Hibernate Validation issue for spring upgrade to 5.2.3

Tags: spring, gwt, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

We are working on a spring upgrade from 4.0.x to 5.2.3.
 The project has validation-api, hibernate-validator, gwt libraries.

I am using the following versions for validatin-api and hibernate-validator:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

GWT libraries are on versions: 2.8.2

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to build the project after updating the spring libraries to 5.2.3, I get the below exception:

```
ERROR - 27.01.2020 20:17:04,546 - org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet(line:534) - initServletBean - Thread:main - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [WebAppClassLoader=446226554@1a98e07a]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:520)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:365)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunWarMojo.execute(JettyRunWarMojo.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [WebAppClassLoader=446226554@1a98e07a]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    ... 68 more
[WARNING] unavailable
```

After reading through couple of posts, I updated the validation-api to 1.1.0.Final. This update added 2 more methods to the AbstractGwtValidatorFactory interface.

```
    @Override
    public ParameterNameProvider getParameterNameProvider() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClockProvider getClockProvider() {
        return null;
    }
```

I added default implementaions where it returns null. On builing the project, I get the following error:

```
/gwt/client/validation/CoreValidatorFactory.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 51: The method getParameterNameProvider() of type CoreValidatorFactory must override or implement a supertype method
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 56: The method close() of type CoreValidatorFactory must override or implement a supertype method.
```

I also tried upgrading hibernate validator to 5.x an 6.x, and validation-api to 2.x, This just added another method "public ClockProvider getClockProvider()" to the interface.

Did anyone come across such issue or can point in the right direction ?